# mount in fstab with krb5 at login

Tags: fstab, cifs, kerberos

I have a `cifs` fileshare that I use. My organisation requires that it uses Kerberos so it's mounted with `sec=krb5`.
This is fine, but I'd like it to mount after login automatically without having to click on the icon on Nautilus.

I can create a `.desktop` entry to `.config/autostart/` but it seems a bit clunky. I was hoping to be able to do it in the `fstab` but I cannot fins the right option. It's currently this;
`$FILEPATH    $DFS_MOUNT    cifs    _netdev,sec=krb5,users,rw    0    0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me in Ubuntu 18.04:
I added an fstab entry for the fileshare directory on the file server:

```
//server.my.domain.name/directory    /mount/point   cifs    noauto,users,_netdev,sec=krb5
```

Then I created a shell script with the file extension .sh in /etc/profile.d to mount the directory on login, but only for users who belong to the appropriate domain:

```
if [[ " $(groups) " =~ ' domain users@my.domain.name ' ]]; then
    mount /mount/point >/dev/null
fi
```

The paths above have been anonymized to protect the guilty ;-}

P.S. If your network takes too long to start, you may need something that takes that into account, such as:

```
for i in {1..30} # give up if server isn't reachable in 30 seconds
do sleep 1 # wait a second
  if [ ping -c1 server.my.domain.name &> /dev/null ]; then
     continue # loop if server can't be reached
  elif [[ " $(groups) " =~ ' domain users@my.domain.name ' ]]; then
     mount /mount/point >/dev/null # mount share once server responds
  fi
done
```

WARNING: This is untested; use at your own risk!